# Check if headless android emulator is running

Tags: android, android-emulator, ui-automation

I am running a headless emulator (Android api 25) on a Ubuntu linux 14 server and I see the below output for the command-

```
$./adb devices

List of devices attached
emulator-5556   device
```

However, If i try to run any other command I get error

```
$./adb shell dumpsys deviceidle get deep
Can't find service: deviceidle


$./adb shell 'pm list packages -f'
Error: Could not access the Package Manager.  Is the system running?
```

How can i verify that my emulator is functional?

Comment: did you get your answer?

Comment: I tried "adb shell getprop" and that seems to be working. Will try pushing a file and see.

Comment: You should add an answer if your solution is different from mine and it works better

Comment: yeah..still researching on it.

Comment: @KaranHarshWardhan I tried to push a file but that isnt working. Also i tried to run 'adb shell pm list packages io.appium.settings' even this isnt running.

Comment: think you think you need to re-install

Answer (score 2):

is `adb devices -l` not working? it should show you the status of the device as well

try  adb push, for eg

```
adb push foo.txt /sdcard/foo.txt
```

or adb install for eg

```
adb -s emulator-5556 install apkname.apk
```

these commands will work with any running emulator/device

all these commands are available on the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb)